# Project Manager Software 2PLAN not launching on UBUNTU 14.04LTS. I need a help, please!

Tags: 14.04

I downloaded the software 2PLAN from their website, unzipped and trying to launch on UBUNTU 14.04LTS and the software not launch properly.

Usually, I used that software on UBUNTU 12.04LTS with no problem, just installing JAVA JDK 7 from Ubuntu software Center. But, that not working for UBUNTU 14.04LTS.

When I click on 2PLAN icon to launch the software, appears the "splash" screen and then the question to locate the WORKSPACE, but the software close after that, registering an error inside the 2PLAN FOLDER.

What I need to do to use the software on UBUNTU 14.04LTS?

Thank you very much for attention and help.